# Python - IBM Watson Speech to Text 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_result'

Tags: python, json, websocket, ibm-watson

I'm developing a program with IBM Watson Speech to Text and currently using Python 2.7. Here's a stub of some code for development:

```
class MyRecognizeCallback(RecognizeCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        RecognizeCallback.__init__(self)

    def on_data(self, data):
        pass

    def on_error(self, error):
        pass

    def on_inactivity_timeout(self, error):
        pass

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(username='*goes here*', password='*goes here*')
speech_to_text.set_detailed_response(True)

f = '/home/user/file.wav'

rate, data = wavfile.read(f)
work = data.tolist()

with open(f, 'rb') as audio_file:

                # Get IBM Watson analytics
                currentModel = "en-US_NarrowbandModel" if rate <= 8000 else "en-US_BroadbandModel"

                x = ""

                print(" - " + f)

                try:

                    # Callback info
                    myRecognizeCallback = MyRecognizeCallback()

                    # X represents the responce from Watson
                    audio_source = AudioSource(audio_file)
                    my_result = speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(
                                    audio_source,
                                    content_type='audio/wav',
                                    timestamps=True,
                                    recognize_callback=myRecognizeCallback,
                                    model=currentModel,
                                    inactivity_timeout=-1,
                                    max_alternatives=0)
                    x = json.loads(json.dumps(my_result, indent=2), object_hook=lambda d: n
                    namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

What I'm expecting to be returned is a JSON object with the results of the file given the above parameters. What instead I'm recieving is an error that looks like this:

```
Error received: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connected'
```

That's the entire traceback - no other errors than that. However, when I try to access the JSON object in further code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/websocket/recognize_listener.py", line 96, in run
    chunk = self.audio_source.input.read(ONE_KB)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Did I forget something or put something in the wrong place?

#### Edit:

My original code had an error in it that I fixed myself. Regardless, I'm still getting the original error. Here's the update:

```
my_result = speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(
                                    audio_source,
                                    content_type='audio/wav',
                                    timestamps=True,
                                    recognize_callback=myRecognizeCallback,
                                    model=currentModel,
                                    inactivity_timeout=None,
                                    max_alternatives=None).get_result()
                    x = json.loads(json.dumps(my_result, indent=2), object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `object_hook=lambda d: n`, in python `lambda d: n` means "a function that takes d, ignores d, and returns n".

I'm guessing n is set to None somewhere else.

If that doesn't work, it may be easier to debug if you break your lambda into a separate function, `def to_named_tuple(object):` perhaps.

Comment: Correction: that was a mistake on my part. This is what it was supposed to look like: `...inactivity_timeout=None,
                                    max_alternatives=None).get_result()
                    x = json.loads(json.dumps(my_result, indent=2), object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))`